# Re-Execute Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found some code from google.A `tesseract` ocr working fine. But The problem is when i put url, frist time working good but second time  run  not working.After reload page then working. I wish to result without page reloading manually.

Demo Image:

[image: Demo Image]

Here Some Html:

```
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />
     <input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />
     <!--<div id="ocr_results"> </div>-->
     <div id="ocr_status"> </div>
     <div>
        <label>Filed1
        <label>
           <textarea id="text"></textarea>
     </div>
</body>
```

Here JavaScript:

```
function runOCR(url) {
    Tesseract.recognize(url)
        .then(function(result) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = result.text;
    }).progress(function(result) {
        document.getElementById("ocr_status").innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
            (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
    });      
}

document.getElementById("go_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    runOCR(url);
});
```

Comment: That image you posted is not working

Comment: @RaulRene It works fine for me - the Url is working.

Comment: Generally you're expected to try and solve the problem yourself, posting code you found on Google and requesting modifications to it with seemingly no effort on your part is not really what this site is for. Do you have any ideas about what is wrong with it? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i have implement ajax,but not working.

Comment: I've tidied your code that you posted, but it's broken.  There are opening tags without relevant closing tags.  You need to fix the HTML before you consider fixing code issues as they could be nothing more than broken HTML.

Comment: ok,but html code is working,nothing any issue

Comment: @khusbukhadi That's perfectly normal for broken HTML - everything *looks* fine.  You should fix it so you can rule out *potential issues*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As `textarea` is a form element use the `value` to assign new values instead of `innerHTML`.
Please find the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h1mrL7ng/